# Apache; Is it possible to have 1 same Alias for 2 different directories?

Tags: apache, directory, localhost, alias, wampserver

Using Wampserver on a windows machine; Is it possible to setup an Apache alias to serve 2 different directories?

Currently I can access `d:/apps/myapp/app/` from `http://localhost/app/` using this alias configuration:

```
Alias /app/ "d:/apps/myapp/app/" 
<Directory "d:/apps/myapp/app/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now I have another app `myapp2` that has a sub folder named `app` too; How can I setup the same alias to look into both directories when visiting `http://localhost/app/`?

Is that even possible!?

Comment: It is a far better idea to use Virtual Hosts rather than Alias's. You wont get this problem and you can address your sites using a sensible url like `myapp1.dev` and `myapp2.dev`. See tutorial here http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,124482 Its written for WampServer 2.5 users specifically but you should be able to pick out the bits specifically about Virtual Hosts.

Comment: Thanks Riggs for the info.. will try Virtual hosts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by using @RiggsFolly advise, and I also wrote a tutorial about it on my blog; [How to easily configure Virtual Hosts on your localhost](http://www.numediaweb.com/configure-virtual-hosts/)